# Server 2016 Essentials and Sage 300

Tags: windows-server-2012

We have a small business and just bought Server 2016 Essentials to run Sage 300. When trying to install Sage 300, it says : "Unsupported Environment - Sage 300 does not support installing on a DC". That's a problem because Essentials Server must be a domain controller. But then says that some features won't work (features we won't use) and gives me the option to proceed anyway. I proceed, but the it doesn't run : "the server the unable to process the request due to an internal error". So, my question is: Can Sage run on Server 2016 Essentials? If not, can I upgrade Essentials to Standard and NOT use/install a domain? Right now we only use the server as a file share. This is a small office and we just wanted a file server to run Sage.

Alternatively, can I remove the DC functionality from Server Essentials 2016?

Comment: If you get rid of the domain controller, you'll lose any domain-based logon accounts, security settings, etc. Is that a desired outcome?

Comment: Yes. I don't want the domain at all. 
We aren't using domain at all. We are using the server just as a file share.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to remove or disable the dc on Essentials but I don't know that that's possible.

Comment: does that mean I can get rid of the domain controller?

Comment: I doubt you can eliminate the DC role from Essentials. Bottom line is the purchase choice was not properly researched and the wrong OS was bought...probably because someone saw the lower price tag and assumed it would work.